# How to redirect only 404 pages with htaccess in Wordpress

Tags: redirect, htaccess, apache

For a client I want to do the following thing with .htaccess:

domainname.com/path must redirect to sub.domainname.com/path, but only if the first page is a deleted page / 404 page.

So all the existing pages must stay intact, and the deleted pages must redirect to a subdomain with the same path.

I used the following code on a Wordpress website, to only redirect 404 error pages to a new domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have overwritten the following code in the existing htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It is not working. The problem is that now ALL pages are redirected to the new domain.

Only the 404's must be redirected.

What do I wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far I understand, .htaccess rewrite rules are executed before the request is proccesed by WordPress, or even by PHP engine, so you can not know if a URL will trigger a 404 error in .htaccess, you can not check if a given path will trigger a 404 at that level. You need to do it in WordPress itself:

```
// See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cyb_redirect_not_found_paths' );
function cyb_redirect_not_found_paths() {

    // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_404/
    if( is_404() ) {

        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/your_path' ) {

            $url_to = 'redirecton_rul';

            // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/
            wp_redirect( $url_to );
            exit;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have to add this code to the functions.php in the template folder right and have to change the 'redirecton_rul' in the code? I have tried it, with no succes. And what to fill at: == '/your_path'. Is it possibile to make the new path automatic the same on the new domain where it is redirected to?

Comment: Of course, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']'` should contain the requested path, so you can append it to any domain of your choice. Please, nothe that your question include a generic "path" and so this answer is a generic approach. You can include the code in functions.php, but it is better to make it a plugin because this code has nothing to do with theming ("look and feel").

Answer (score 0):

Use this direction:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
```